# Magnific Popup Gallery not working

Tags: jquery, html, magnific-popup

I'm trying to create a gallery with the Magnific Popup Lightbox Gallery plugin. I have checked the documentation by Dmitry Semenov and copied the code blocks exactly as he stated. This is my `<head>` section where I have all the files included:

```
<head>
 <title>Gallery</title>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/core_styles_gallery2.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/magnific-popup.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jquery.magnific-popup.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/jQuery_gallery.js"></script>
</head>
```

As you can see there's simply the bootstrap files and my css sheets, the jQuery library file, plus the 2 .css and .js files for the magnific popup that the developer says to include. Here is my HTML gallery block of code (the class "hoverZoomLink" was used by the dev in his example):

```
<div class="article-content">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="popup-gallery">
                <a href="styles/images/gallery/image.jpg" class="hoverZoomLink"><img src="styles/images/gallery/image.jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
                <a href="styles/images/gallery/image(1).jpg" class="hoverZoomLink"><img src="styles/images/gallery/image(1).jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
                <a href="styles/images/gallery/image(2).jpg" class="hoverZoomLink"><img src="styles/images/gallery/image(2).jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
                <a href="styles/images/gallery/image(3).jpg" class="hoverZoomLink"><img src="styles/images/gallery/image(3).jpg" width="75" height="75"></a>
            </div>  
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Finally, this is the jQuery code (located in the external jQuery_gallery.js file I included in the `<head>` ) that is supposed to initialise the popup:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.popup-gallery').magnificPopup({
    delegate: 'a',
    type: 'image',
    tLoading: 'Loading image #%curr%...',
    mainClass: 'mfp-img-mobile',
    gallery: {
        enabled: true,
        navigateByImgClick: true,
        preload: [0,1] // Will preload 0 - before current, and 1 after the current image
    },
    image: {
        tError: '<a href="%url%">The image #%curr%</a> could not be loaded.',
        titleSrc: function(item) {
            return item.el.attr('title') + '<small>by Marsel Van Oosten</small>';
        }
    }
});});
```

Well, nothing is working. When I click on the images, they simply open in another tab. I am new to programming and web development, I have tried to understand the errors but I have no idea what am I doing wrong. Please help me!

Comment: Could you try removing 1 of the jquery.min.js links in the header? Sometimes it messes up when jquery is declared twice. Edit; make sure you're not missing any /'s in the directory

Comment: nope, just tried now removing it. Nothing changes..

Comment: Added an answer to show some code you could try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like this to start with the basic like the example from the developers page (change the href and src ofcourse):

```
<a href="image.jpg" class="image-link">
   <img src="thumbnails.jpg" />
</a> 

// Initialize popup as usual
$('.image-link').magnificPopup({
  type: 'image',
  mainClass: 'mfp-with-zoom', // this class is for CSS animation below

  zoom: {
    enabled: true, // By default it's false, so don't forget to enable it

    duration: 300, // duration of the effect, in milliseconds
    easing: 'ease-in-out', // CSS transition easing function


    opener: function(openerElement) {
      return openerElement.is('img') ? openerElement : openerElement.find('img');
    }
  }

});
```

See if this works, if this doesn't work either it's not the code that's wrong.

Edit: 
Searched for an fully working example, try the following code:

```
<a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/eee/000.jpg" data-group="1" class="galleryItem test">group 1 image 1</a> – 
<a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.jpg" data-group="1" class="galleryItem test123">group 1 image 2</a>

<br/><br/>

<a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x200/000/fff.jpg" data-group="3" class="galleryItem">group 2 image 1</a> – 
<a href="http://dummyimage.com/600x900/000/fff.jpg" data-group="3" class="galleryItem">group 2 image 2</a>
```

and in the JS:

```
var groups = {};
$('.galleryItem').each(function() {
  var id = parseInt($(this).attr('data-group'), 10);

  if(!groups[id]) {
    groups[id] = [];
  } 

  groups[id].push( this );
});


$.each(groups, function() {

  $(this).magnificPopup({
      type: 'image',
      closeOnContentClick: true,
      closeBtnInside: false,
      gallery: { enabled:true }
  })

});
```

Comment: No, it doesen't work. Still simply opening every image in a new browser tab... So if you say the code isn't the problem, then what is?

Comment: Could it possibly have anything to do with the fact that I'm using the jQuery script in a separate file? I know that's the recommended way, but should I put it between <script> tags in the HTML?

Comment: Did you include the zoom module? Edit; you could try putting it inside the script tag to see if it does anything.

Comment: I tried checking the console in the browser developer mode, and it gives me this error: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <              jquery.magnific-popup.js "   What is this?

Comment: I had that error before, make you sure declare your JS like this: <script type="text/javascript"> and make sure you close it with </script> Also make sure you aren't opening the <script> twice. Had that before also.